# ElasticSearch ignore fields that are not in mappings when creating index

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a template, that set `dynamic` to false. Everyday, a new index would be created based on this new template, when the first doc comes to the data stream. We have fields defined in the template's mappings session. We'd like the newly created index mapping not containing whatever fields that appear in the doc, but not in the template's mappings.

The `dynamic` field in the mappings session seems not working for this. Could anyone suggest? Our current version is 7.14

Comment: What you are describing is too big of a bug to survive until 7.14. I think something important is missing in your question.I tried reproducing it with 7.14.0, and as expected the undeclared fields don't show up. Please, take a look at the repro - https://gist.github.com/imotov/b95fc72ca39b7e6c353cb27b28bdb730 and try modifying it to match your issue.